# Pandas: plot a dataframe containing a column of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a non-standard CSV file that looks something like this:

```
x,y
1,"(5, 27, 4)"
2,"(3, 1, 6, 2)"
3,"(4, 5)"
```

Using `pd.read_csv()` leads to something that's not all that useful, because the tuples are not parsed. There are a existing answers that address this ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661583/reading-back-tuples-from-a-csv-file-with-pandas), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550414/how-to-split-column-of-tuples-in-pandas-dataframe)), but because these tuples have heterogeneous lengths, those answers aren't entirely useful for the problem I'm having.

What I'd like to do is plot `x` vs `y` using the pandas plotting routines. The naive approach leads to an error because the tuples are stored as strings:

```
>>> # df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3],
                       'y': ["(5, 27, 4)","(3, 1, 6, 2)","(4, 5)"]})
>>> df.plot.scatter('x', 'y')
[...]
ValueError: scatter requires y column to be numeric
```

The result I'd hope for is something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for x, y in zip(df['x'], df['y']):
    y = eval(y)
    plt.scatter(x * np.ones_like(y), y, color='blue')
```

[image]

Is there a straightforward way to create this plot directly from Pandas, by transforming the dataframe and using `df.plot.scatter()` (and preferably without using `eval()`)?

Comment: If you're worried about the safety of eval, you could use something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763116/parse-a-tuple-from-a-string or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19334399/8131703

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could explode the `df` and `plot`

```
In [3129]: s = df.y.map(ast.literal_eval)

In [3130]: dff = pd.DataFrame({'x': df.x.repeat(s.str.len()).values,
                               'y': np.concatenate(s.values)})

In [3131]: dff
Out[3131]:
   x   y
0  1   5
1  1  27
2  1   4
3  2   3
4  2   1
5  2   6
6  2   2
7  3   4
8  3   5
```

And, plot

```
dff.plot.scatter('x', 'y')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.str` accessor to extract integers, specifically [`.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html):

```
# Index by 'x' to retain its values once we extract from 'y'
df = df.set_index('x')

# Extract integers from 'y'
df = df['y'].str.extractall(r'(\d+)')[0].astype('int64')

# Rename and reset the index (remove 'match' level, get 'x' as column)
df = df.rename('y').reset_index(level='match', drop=True).reset_index()
```

If you have floats instead of ints, just modify the regex and `astype` as appropriate.

This gives a DataFrame that looks like:

```
   x   y
0  1   5
1  1  27
2  1   4
3  2   3
4  2   1
5  2   6
6  2   2
7  3   4
8  3   5
```

And from there `df.plot.scatter('x', 'y')` should produce the expected plot.