# Writing a data frame of mixed types to file Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
Col1, Col 2, Col3
'abc', (1,2), [(1,2), (3,4)]
'xyz', (3,4), [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
```

I have written the data frame to file using `df.to_csv("dataframe.csv")`

When I read the dataframe by `file = pd.read_csv("dataframe.csv")`, I get `Col2` and `Col3` as strings.
However, I would like to read `Col2` as a tuple, and `Col3` as a list of tuples.

How can I do that?
Alternatively, is there another way that I should write the data frame to file, so that I can read the columns in the desired formats?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading back tuples from a csv file with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661583/reading-back-tuples-from-a-csv-file-with-pandas)

Comment: Try pickle.  `df.to_pickle` and `pd.read_pickle`

Answer (score 1):

`file = pd.read_csv("f500.csv", dtype = {"Col2" : np.object, "Col3": np.object})`